# Move uploaded file inside a server

Tags: php, apache, upload, hosting, cpanel

I'm trying to move an uploaded file inside my server on my Cpanel hosting. I am using the PHP function move_uploaded_file, but how do I know  the exact path of my Server?

I tried using this syntax:

```
move_uploaded_file($filelocation, http://website.com/thisfolder/filename.txt);
```

i do know that my file location variable is outputting correctly as I could see that it goes into var/ directory of the server.

I want the path in my filemanager that has the public_html folder.

```
/ServerName1/ServerName2/public_html/Folder1/thisfolder
```

How do I place it into the correct directory?

Comment: have you tried using relative pathing `../thisfolder`.  That might work if `thisfolder` is in the same project directory as the move_upload_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

A sample code of how to upload to a directory. You can find more examples here : https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file

Comment: I followed it, replaced the http with the variable with the server path on it. Thanks.